# Changing from manual App Store submission to fastlane

Tags: ios, app-store, provisioning-profile, fastlane

I was thinking of setting up fastlane to submit my app instead of submitting it manually, which is time-consuming. Would that mean I have to redo everything from scratch i.e. provisioning profile, certs and app name/ description (found in metadata) as that info is already set up in App Store? Would switching over cause any issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/ Is a good introduction to get started. If your app is already on the store Fastlane will get all the metadata, screenshots, identifier etc.

With regards to certificates and provisioning profiles you can either choose to set everything up "completely new" with `match` or use your existing ones with `cert` and `sigh`

Later option really depends on how many people/apps are involved.

Comment: I will say that I recently switched to using Fastlane to manage 1000+ apps on the store and it couldn't have been more seamless. Just give it a shot, follow the docs, and I think you'll be pleasantly surprised

Comment: @Oddie thank you for the detailed reply. It's helpful

Comment: @Nwilson thank you for sharing your experience. I will give it a shot.